# How do you write a integral of a complex function when you know it is real?

Tags: fourier-analysis

Let $g(x)  = f(x) + ih(x)$. Here, $x$ is real, so the function takes a real number and spits out a complex number.

A book I am reading says that if $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ix} g(x) dx$ is a real number, then $f(x)$ is even, and $h(x)$ is odd.

Why is this true?

The book further says that this can be used to write$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ix} g(x) dx = 2\int_0^\infty e^{-ix}g(x) dx$$

Why is this true?

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't say something like "if $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ikx} g(x) dx$ is real for all real $k$"

Answer (score 0):

Note

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ix} g(x) dx=  $$
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty( [\cos(x) f(x) + \sin(x)h(x) ]-i[\sin(x) f(x) -\cos(x)h(x)] )dx$$

If $f(x)$ is even and $h(x)$ odd, the imaginary part of the integrand

$$\sin(x) f(x) -\cos(x)h(x)$$

is odd as a whole and its integration over $(-\infty, \infty)$  vanishes.  Hence, the overall integral is real.

Furthermore, the real part of the integrand is even, and its integral can then be written as two times of its integral over $(0, \infty)$.